# Menu is not showing up in certain browser

Tags: magento-1.9, css, topmenu

Hi I am working in magento 1.9.2.2. Menu and its submenu items are created and working fine.when I reduce the browser size in desktop the menus are appearing perfectly according to the media query. But when opened in real devices like ipad and tablet it is not visible according to the media query. What is happening. Kindly someone help me out.

This is my code to enable it after 770px of browser:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:770px){
 #custommenu{
 display:block !important;
 margin-top:-3px !important;}
 }
```

Comment: Do you using default magento theme or custom theme

Comment: am using custom theme. Extension Gomage is used for menu.

Comment: Is there no solution for this?